# Provide custom IP address for a hostname in network request

Tags: ios, networking, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'd like to make **HTTPS** request in ObjC code, providing custom IP address for the server.

Something like what `--resolv` option for `curl` does.

> `--resolve <host:port:address>`
>
> Provide a custom address for a specific host and port pair. Using
>   this, you can make the curl requests(s) use a specified address and
>   prevent the otherwise normally resolved address to be used. Consider
>   it a sort of /etc/hosts alternative provided on the command line.

I think of two different approaches:

1. Create a usual network request, then intervene somewhere in between and alter IP address.
2. Find/Write a custom network requests library, which will do the low-level stuff by itself.

I could not figure out how to carry out 1st approach and the 2nd looks extremely laborious, no luck with brief googling.

Does someone know a library, which has a functionality to provide an IP address for HTTPS requests or supports custom DNS resolver functions? Or maybe I'm just missing something obvious here.

Comment: just hit the desired IP directly, and set an appropriate `Host:` header. that's basically all `--resolve` would do for http requests anyways.

Comment: But I need strict **HTTPS**!

Comment: Ha! https://github.com/PonyCui/PPEtcHosts looks like an exact match, will post an update.